# How to get rid of 500 or 504 error if redis stops working

Tags: php, nginx, caching, redis, redis-cluster

Currently I am using `redis php client` from

https://github.com/predis/predis

If `redis` stops working, it throws `500 error`. I want to modify in source code of `library` itself as it is implemented in many of our applications.

How can I bypass this `500 error` as even though I bypass it, it will give `504 gateway timeout` error.

Any hints will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

There are lots of old applications with `Try/Catch` already written in lots of `codes`. We want to move ahead with normal process without `redis` if fails. We simply don't want show `500`/`504` etc on page.

**EDIT 2:**

There are lots of codes in applications without `Try/Catch` too, which will take colossal time to check line by line and implement `Try/Catch`. That's why we need to make some changes in `predis lib` to get rid of those `errors/exceptions`.

Comment: What do you want it to do instead exactly? The whole point of a 500 error is precisely to warn you that something has stopped working and you need to fix it

Comment: If the rest of your application can cope with the absence of redis some of the time, are you actually wanting to _catch_ the error perhaps, in the code which uses your library? It wasn't clear what you mean by "bypass it" in your question- what are you actually doing to achieve that?

Comment: Are you doing any error handling? Try/catch for example?

Comment: @MarkusZeller Yes but we want to move ahead without redis if it fails since lots application uses it we want it to change in lib itself

Comment: That's a bad idea, to mess with library code because then you become incompatible with future updates and fixes for it. Just use some try/catch in your applications

Comment: @ADyson, you are correct. Thing is there are lots of old applications with Try/Catch already written in lots of codes. We want to move ahead with normal process without redis if fails. We simply don't want show 500/504 etc on page.

Comment: Have you tried something like this, where the error redirects to another location that doesn’t use redis https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/redis/

Comment: `there are lots of old applications with Try/Catch already written`...ok so what precisely is the issue then? Is that technique not helping?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think redis library is trowing a 500, but you app not handling errors correctly. What about an error handler?